# YoY in Google Looker Studio?

Tags: google-data-studio, google-data-studio-charts

I connected Google Looker Studio a.k.a. Data Studio to a database with sales data from 5 years ago until now.

When I plot the data onto a [*stacked bar chart*](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/7165560?hl=en#other-types-of-bar-charts), the current year lags behind because we're in October now and there is only 10 months worth of data, as opposed to the full previous years.

Is there an easy way to make this a Year-on-Year (YoY) chart? Either by configuring the chart itself, or by tampering with the source data from the previous years? This way it will be limited respectively to no later than the current day and month.

Manual filters, excluding data from October 20 to the end of the year for every previous year, worked as a proof of concept.

[image: Manual filter screenshot]

Of course having it manual all the time is not sustainable.

Is there any way to make them dynamic, excluding from `NOW()` until the end of the year?